# Securing thick client with IdentityServer4

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-core, web, identityserver4

I am implementing a web application with security via IS4. My idea is to make the actual application running local identity server also be an endpoint for managing it: modifying clients, users, and resources and what not.

I don't want to separate the actual database work into a standalone API, and would prefer to keep this client thick. But this would make this webapp both a client and a protected resource.

How is this supposed to be implemented in terms of IS4? Do I register my app as both a client and an API? Is there a cleaner mechanism in IdentityServer4 for doing this sort of "self-check"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add user management related apis into the application which running Identity Server . You can make use of ASP.NET Identity and EF Core to manage users/roles.

Your client app will authenticate via identity server application , and also acquire access token for accessing the protected user management apis in IDS app . Identity server app needs to add JWT Bearer authentication schema which accepts the api request(with token in header) , then you should add Authorize attribute to challenge the bearer authentication  on the protected api controllers/actions  .